# Ruby: day selection program (select next available day from a list)

Tags: ruby, date

I'm tryind to build a helper to select the next available day from a list.

I have a list of days as a reference (those are the day where I want something to happen)

```
class_list = ["Monday","Saturday","Sunday"]
```

I need to check the current day and match it in the list.
If it's part of the list I select it, if it isn't I select the next one from the list.

this is what i have so far:

```
#select current day, get its name value and weekday number value
today = Time.now
today_name = today.strftime("%A")
#not sure which of the 2 following line is better
#today_index = DateTime.parse(today_name).wday 
today_index = today.strftime("%u").to_i
```

Then I do the matching

```
if class_list.include? today_name
  #victory!!!
  puts today_name
else
  puts "find next day"
  class_list.each do |x|
    if DateTime.parse(x).wday > today_index
      puts "result #{x}"
      break
    end
  end
end
```

When I run it  seems to work fine, but as i'm just learning Ruby i'm always wondering if i'm not overcomplicating things.

Does this code looks alright to you Ruby masters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'date'

def next_date_from(ar)
  cur_day = Date.today
  cur_day += 1 until ar.include?(cur_day.strftime('%A'))
  cur_day
end

puts next_date_from(%w(Monday Saturday Sunday))
#=>2011-10-01
```

Comment: So Ruby is clever enough to understand that when you add 1 to a date object it means the next day? And I love Date.today. Couldn't find it in the doc :(

Comment: [doc for Date.today](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/Date.html#M000411). Ruby also does >>1 and <<1 (for months)

Answer (score 1):

I would better have a map linking a given day to the following one and a default value if the day is not found:

```
days = {:Monday => :Tuesday, :Tuesday => :Wednesday ...}
days.default = :Monday
```

When you do days[:Monday] you get :Tuesday
when you try to get a non existing entry, you get the default.

Comment: What I actually want to do is a day switcher so that it displays the current day or the next available one in the list. I like the idea of the default state that I could instantiate in case the date picker doesn't work. but I need to keep rotating the days.

Answer (score 1):

For the part:

```
if class_list.include? today_name
  #victory!!!
  puts today_name
else
  puts "find next day"
  class_list.each do |x|
    if DateTime.parse(x).wday > today_index
      puts "result #{x}"
      break
    end
  end
end
```

You could write it like this:

```
if class_list.include? today_name
  #victory!!!
  puts today_name
else
  puts "find next day"
  result = class_list.find {|e| DateTime.parse(e).wday > today_index }
  puts "result = #{result}"
end
```

Comment: .find return the first result?

Comment: Yes. And `.select` finds all matching the condition.